# None of the unofficial Pandora clients are working on my Phone

Tags: music

None of the unofficial Pandora clients are working on my Phone, the application runs but no audio output. I have tried all

1.MetroRadio
2.Radio Controlled
3.WpFandora
What could be the reason

Comment: Does the sound work from any other application? do you have the volume off?

Comment: I assume that you are in one of the countries where Pandora is available i.e. US, NZ and OZ?

Comment: While odd none of them work, Pandora frequently changes their API, breaking unofficial 3rd party apps. I've even read rumors they do this specifically to bust WP7 apps (though given market share I don't know why they'd bother).

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if you still have that problem, but according to [wp central](http://www.wpcentral.com/pandora-comments-windows-phone-and-metroradio-returns-more-streaming), the broken apps are back online.